# Precision of floating point - C++03

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

Suppose i do the following:

```
Example A:
float i = 123.0f;
std::cout << i;
```

I'll get the output `123`

My question is when the default precision of float is 6 for `std::cout` why do I get the output 123 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) to show these insignificant zeroes. By default, extra zeroes are cropped for readability.

```
double f = 3.14159;
std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
std::cout << std::fixed;
std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
```

Outputs:

```
3.1416
3.14159
3.14159
3.141590000
```